# Unable to set count value to column

Tags: android, sql, database, android-room

I am trying to fetch a component category that has a certain amount of components in a rack.

### Query

```
@Query("SELECT id, name, component_amount = " +
        "       (SELECT COUNT(component.id) as amount " +
        "        FROM component " +
        "        WHERE component.rack_id = :rackID AND component_cat.id = component_cat_id ) " +
        "FROM component_cat")
LiveData<List<ComponentCat>> getRackComponentCategories(long rackID);
```

---

### ComponentCat

```
public class ComponentCat
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public long componentCatID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String componentCatName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "component_amount")
    private int amountOfComponents;


    public ComponentCat(String componentCatName, int amountOfComponents) {
        this.componentCatName = componentCatName;
        this.amountOfComponents = amountOfComponents;
    }
```

---

Testing this in PHPMyAdmin it works, but putting this SQL in my Room application, I get the following error:

```
  error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [amountOfComponents] in com.mwb.digitalstorage.model.ComponentCat even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [id,name,component_amount =        (SELECT COUNT(component.id) as amount         FROM component         WHERE component.rack_id = :rackID AND component_cat.id = component_cat_id )]
```

In Room, how do I set the variable `amountOfComponents` to the `COUNT()` result?

I have tried:

- Having a COUNT(component.id) as component_amount, but such does not give the right outcome
- Re-creating the table in MySQL and perform the same query, which did give the right outcome
- Removing @NonNull at the fields, no difference
- assigning the component_amount.amount

  @Query("SELECT id, name, component_amount.amount = " +
          "       (SELECT COUNT(component.id) as amount " ...

  this does not build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room does not support this type of giving an alias to your columns.

Your error Message states :

```
Columns returned by the query: [id,name,component_amount =        (SELECT COUNT(component.id) as amount         FROM component         WHERE component.rack_id = :rackID AND component_cat.id = component_cat_id )
```

Which means it is interpreting the whole query as a column.

Try changing your Query to the following:

```
@Query("SELECT id, name, " +
        "       (SELECT COUNT(component.id) as amount " +
        "        FROM component " +
        "        WHERE component.rack_id = :rackID AND component_cat.id = component_cat_id ) as component_amount " +
        "FROM component_cat")
LiveData<List<ComponentCat>> getRackComponentCategories(long rackID);
```

Comment: "Which means it is interpreting the whole query as a column" that is what I am aiming for, the outcome of that query assigned to the column. It works in PHPMyAdmin, but didn't at Room. Your answer does work in Room. Thank you